# Wordpress - HTML to wordpress conversion

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slideshow

I am new to Wordpress so please bear me for this type of question.I have an html page which has a slideshow. The images are loading from html page not javascript.So I am now trying to convert the page into wordpress(make it dynamic). first I want to know how can I create a position there in html page and then how can I set up in backend panel the multiimage upload option so that Multiple images will show into the slideshow. If It has to be one image then I can do this but as I have to show multiple images I dont know How can I do this. and I dont want some new slideshow plugins. I need this thing to work.please if there any plugin or tutorial that can help me to do this task then please share it.
Advance thanks

Comment: If the page already works as plain HTML and JavaScript, can't it work as-is inside of WordPress?  Doesn't WordPress support HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: iT supports. But I want the page to be dynamic so that i CAN upload the photos from backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is the [jQuery cycle2 plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/), it runs based on html attributes and doesn't require any javascript programming for basic functionality.  If you want the slides to be manageable in the admin of wordpress you will need to install something like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) which will require some programming but not much.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Wordpress plugin for cycle slideshow, https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cycle/ .